# Store Subtitles in a Database

Tags: python, json, django, database, asynchronous

I'm working on a project that uses AI to recognise the speech of an audio file. The output of this AI is a huge JSON object with tons of values. I'll remove some keys, and the final structure will look as follows.

```json
{
    text: "<recognised text>",
    language: "<detected language>"
    segments: [
        {startTimestamp: "00:00:00", endTimestamp: "00:00:10", text: "<some text>"},
        {startTimestamp: "00:00:10", endTimestamp: "00:00:17", text: "<some text>"},
        {startTimestamp: "00:00:17", endTimestamp: "00:00:26", text: "<some text>"},
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

Now, I wish to store this new trimmed object in a SQL database because I wish to be able to edit it manually. I'll create a React application to edit segments, delete segments, etc. Additionally, I want to add this feature to the React application, where the information will be saved every 5 seconds using an AJAX call.

Now, I don't understand how I should store this object in the SQL database. Initially, I thought I would store the whole object as a string in a database. Whenever some change is made to the object, I'll send a JSON object from the React application, the backend will sanitize it and then replace the old stringified object in the database with the new sanitised string object. This way updating and deletion will happen with ease but there can be issues in case of searching. But I'm wondering if there are any better approaches to do this.

Could someone guide me on this?

Tech Stack

- **Frontend** - React
- **Backend** - Django 3.2.15
- **Database** - PostgreSQL

Thank you

Comment: It's opinion based question, but don't store it as JSON in database, it's really hard to maintain. Creating separate table is much better aproach in my opinion

Comment: You should store it as a Django Model, if you use Django Rest Framework with Django ORM it should be very easy to work it out, but yes do not store JSON in database.

Comment: Let's say to store the segments in a Django model, I create a `Segment` model and to maintain the relative ordering of the segments, I add a `previous` field. This field will store the ID of the previous segment. Now let's say I break a segment into two segments, `00:00:00 - 00:00:10` to `00:00:00 - 00:00:05` and `00:00:05 - 00:00:10`. How should I handle such as situation because the database wouldn't have these two new segments?

Comment: You don't need to add "previous" field, every x seconds filter your qs to get segments where startTimestamp < time_since_film_start < endTimestamp and order by startTimestamp

Comment: Makes sense. I can order the queryset in ascending order based on the endTimestamp. And, considering the example in the last comment, when I'm updating the segments, I'll delete all the segments that are present in the database but not in the JSON object received (`00:00:00 - 00:00:10`). Next, I'll save the new segments to the database (`00:00:00 - 00:00:05` and `00:00:05 - 00:00:10`). Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right, you may even use DurationField to strore timdelta objects

Comment: Yeah. I used a `DurationField` for the timestamps and since they store `timedelta` objects, I can easily perform comparisons. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I don't understand how I should store this object in the SQL database. Initially, I thought I would store the whole object as a string in a database.

If the data has a *clear structure*, you should **not** store it as a JSON blob in a *relational* database. While relational databases have some support for JSON nowadays, it is still not very effective, and normally it means you can not effectively filter, aggregate, and manipulate data, nor can you check referential integrity.

You can work with two models that look like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Q


class Subtitle(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Segment(models.Model):
    startTimestamp = models.DurationField()
    endTimestamp = models.DurationField()
    subtitle = models.ForeignKey(
        Subtitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='segments'
    )
    text = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('subtitle', 'startTimestamp', 'endTimestamp')
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(startTimestamp__gt=F('endTimestamp')),
                name='start_before_end',
            )
        ]
```

This will also guarantee that the `startTimestamp` is before the `endTimestamp` for example, that these fields store durations (and not `"foo"` for example).

You can convert from and to JSON with [*serializers* <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/):

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['startTimestamp', 'endTimestamp', 'text']


class SubtitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    segments = SegmentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Subtitle
        fields = ['text', 'language', 'segments']
```

Comment: Thank you. I implement something similar. I had a weird bug in the ordering of segments but `ordering = ('startTimestamp', 'endTimestamp')` solved it. I'm just confused about one thing. What is the purpose of `text = models.CharField(max_length=512)` if there is already a `Subtitle` model to store the text and language?

Comment: @Vaibhav: it contains the text of that segment, as in your `{ ... , "text": ... }` parts.